# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Math.random (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to take the last ten lotteries numbers and try to combine them to 14 random guesses.
What I did is to define 2 arrays, one with the all numbers and one with the strong number.
With that, I want to generate 14 combine guesses but when I my loop is more than 4 I got an error with the title above.
Can someone explain me what is my problem ? Thanks :]
Code:

```js
const paisRsultsNumbers = [
    2,15,19,33,34,36,1,2,13,14,22,36,3,5,13,23,24,35,1,3,4,13,20,37,2,6,10,11,16,35,2,5,6,7,15,30,2,7,8,10,30,31,5,13,15,21,22,33,3,5,7,9,19,27,1,7,16,23,28,34
]

const paisResultsStrongNumber = [
    7,7,1,5,6,7,1,7,5,5
]

const guesses = [];
const gen_nums = [];

function getRandSixNumbers(){
    let nums = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        nums.push(getRandNum(paisRsultsNumbers));
    }

    return nums;
}
getRandSixNumbers()

function getRandStrongNumber(){
    return paisResultsStrongNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * paisResultsStrongNumber.length)]
}

function isInArray(array, el) {
    for(let i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
        if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
 }
 
function getRandNum(array) {
    let rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!isInArray(gen_nums, rand)) {
        gen_nums.push(rand); 
        return rand;
    }
    
    return getRandNum(array);     
}

 (function createGuess(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        guesses.push({
            six: [getRandSixNumbers()],
            strongNumber: getRandStrongNumber()
        })
    }

    console.log(guesses)
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getRandNum(array) {
    let rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!isInArray(gen_nums, rand)) {
        gen_nums.push(rand); 
        return rand;
    }
    
    return getRandNum(array);     
}
```

`getRandStrongNumber` tries to pick a random unique number among `paisRsultsNumbers` array. It's fine when you try less than the total unique numbers. But when you exceed that your `getRandStrongNumber` function will keep calling itself endlessly. And 6*14 will exceed that number for sure.

**Edit:**

You can reset the `gen_nums` array after you pick the 6 unique random numbers in your loop.

```
let gen_nums = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 14; i++){
    guesses.push({
       six: [getRandSixNumbers()],
       strongNumber: getRandStrongNumber()
      })
    gen_nums = []
}
```

Comment: I try to understand what you said. But what solution I have for this issue ?

Comment: @adirpeer Do you need those numbers to be unique or not? If yes you need a larger array that has at least 84 (6*14) unique items else you can remove the `isInArray` check.

Comment: No I want it as is.
Just pick from the paisRsultsNumbers array 6 random numbers and one  random from paisResultsStrongNumber. It can be with same numbers.

Comment: @adirpeer you can reset the `gen_nums` array in your loop. See the updated answer.

Comment: It does not work. I get an error: app.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at createGuess
My problem related to getRandNum function, because I return a call for it if the rand number placed inside the array.

Comment: @adirpeer you need to change your `gen_nums` declaration to `let` from `const`